# How to append string to the end of selective linesin bash

Tags: bash

I have three columns of data in one file, i.e.

```
  0.464980006         0.237939999         0.000000000
  0.464980006         0.737940013         0.000000000
  0.964980006         0.237939999         0.000000000
  0.964980006         0.737940013         0.000000000
  0.298310012         0.404610008         0.068700001
  0.298310012         0.904609978         0.068700001
  0.798309982         0.404610008         0.068700001
  0.798309982         0.904609978         0.068700001
```

Now I want to append F F F to the end of each line, how should I achieve it?

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -n +9 POSCAR | head -n 24 | sort -k3 | head -8 > o-bot-layer
tail -n +9 POSCAR | head -n 24 | sort -k3 | tail -16 > o-sur-layer
tail -n +33 POSCAR | sort -k3 | head -4 > ce-bot-layer
tail -n +33 POSCAR | sort -k3 | tail -8 > ce-sur-layer

cat o-bot-layer | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,"F F F"}' > o-bot-layer

head -n 8 POSCAR > lat

cat o-sur-layer >> lat
cat o-bot-layer >> lat
cat ce-sur-layer >> lat
cat ce-bot-layer >> lat
mv lat pos.str
rm o-sur-layer o-bot-layer ce-sur-layer ce-bot-layer
```

It doesn't work. I tried sed 's/$' and awk '{print $0, ""}' in other people's post, the weird thing is I only get it append to the beginning of the line, not the end.

Something like this:

```
 F F F0002 0.571280003 0.137400001
  F F F0017 0.071280003 0.137400001
  F F F0017 0.571280003 0.137400001
  F F F0006 0.237939999 0.206110001
  F F F0006 0.737940013 0.206110001
  F F F0006 0.237939999 0.206110001
  F F F0006 0.737940013 0.206110001
  F F F0012 0.404610008 0.274809986
  F F F0012 0.904609978 0.274809986
  F F F9982 0.404610008 0.274809986
  F F F9982 0.904609978 0.274809986
  F F F0002 0.071280003 0.343510002
  F F F0002 0.571280003 0.343510002
  F F F0017 0.071280003 0.343510002
  F F F0017 0.571280003 0.343510002
  F F F0006 0.237939999 0.000000000
  F F F0006 0.737940013 0.000000000
  F F F0006 0.237939999 0.000000000
  F F F0006 0.737940013 0.000000000
  F F F0012 0.404610008 0.068700001
  F F F0012 0.904609978 0.068700001
  F F F9982 0.404610008 0.068700001
  F F F9982 0.904609978 0.068700001
  F F F0012 0.404610008 0.171749994
  F F F0012 0.904609978 0.171749994
  F F F9982 0.404610008 0.171749994
```

I suspect there are some hidden thing in my file format, something like \n at the beginning of each line so sed $s would think the beginning of line is the end of line. I am not sure...

Thank you!

Comment: What about the "selective" part?

Comment: Very annoying problems:

Comment: It only prepend and replace the beginning of each line but rather append to the end of line. I copy and paste the lines to a new file and then it can work, I am wondering if it is because some unseen and suspicious charracters in my lines

Comment: I can't possibly read that as unformatted comments - please [edit] the question to add information.

Comment: It only prepend and partially replace to the beginning of each line, but do not append to the end of each line, Ahhh.....

Comment: @LeiZhang : Nice that you've put some effort to solve this, please edit te question and put the code there.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, my goodness. I got it.

The file POSCAR I got is fishy.

I guess it is from windows, so it contains some dos format that can be misleading in unix environment.

I first convert it using

```
dos2unix POSCAR
```

and then run my code, everything now works fine, just like other people's post!

Any guru can explain it further this fishy dos format?

Comment: It's the line endings: different OSs use different newline representations, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 0):

- First thing what is the source of the file POSCAR
- if you copy paste, there is possibility of the non displayable chars
- i tried to browsed through and found out, might you it will help you to find the source

  ```
  Unicode Character 'START OF TEXT' (U+0002)
  Unicode Character 'DEVICE CONTROL TWO' (U+0012)
  Unicode Character 'END OF TRANSMISSION BLOCK' (U+0017)
  ```

Any ways see if this helps

```
sed -E 's;^(.*);F F F\1;g' POSCAR
```